# Ghostscript unrecoverable error undefinedfilename

Tags: syntax-error, ghostscript, solution

**PROBLEM**

Many sites are trying to explain it, but error message is pretty unclear. In my case I had a lot of pdf files to merge and for some reason one file was a big problem.

```
Ghostscript unrecoverable error undefinedfilename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

If you got this message then merge files with asterix

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dSAFER -sOutputFile=out.pdf *.pdf
```

If out.pdf is OK It means "your file path or file does not exist". Now is the message "undefinedfilename" already clear.

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error by neglecting the dash before dBATCH.  So

`gs dBATCH ...`

instead of

`gs -dBATCH ...`